# <geotools/HeatmapProcess> convert GridCoverage2d to BufferedImage

Tags: wms, geotools, image, heat-map, png

I got the heatmapprocessTest code from geotools github
However, I can't confirm that the heat map is coming out well.
Ultimately I want to create and save the heatmap as a BufferedImage. (png)
For example, I want to make it like the picture below.
[image]

Please share with me the code to image the GridCoverage2D with the heatmap drawn.
please!!!

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    
    ReferencedEnvelope bounds = new ReferencedEnvelope(0, 10, 0, 10, crs);
    Coordinate[] data = {
            new Coordinate(4.0, 4.0),
            new Coordinate(5.0, 6.0),
            new Coordinate(2.0, 6,0)
    };
    SimpleFeatureCollection fc = createPoints(data, bounds); 
    ProgressListener monitor = null;
    HeatmapProcess process = new HeatmapProcess();
    GridCoverage2D cov = process.execute(
                    fc, // data
                    1, // radius
                    null, // weightAttr
                    0, // pixelsPerCell
                    bounds, // outputEnv
                    1920, // outputWidth
                    1080, // outputHeight
                    monitor // monitor)
                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`getRenderedImage()`](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/coverage/grid/GridCoverage2D.html#getRenderedImage--) method on `GridCoverage2D` which returns a `RenderedImage` which you can write out in the normal Java way:

```
File out = new File("test.jpg");
Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg");
ImageWriter writer = null;
while (writers.hasNext()) {
  writer = writers.next();
  // break;
}
writer.setOutput(new ImageOutputStreamAdapter(new FileOutputStream(out)));
writer.write(grid.getRenderedImage());
```

Or if you might need to use the image in a GIS later, you could use the `WorldImageWriter` which will produce a *world* file to georeference the image:

```
File out2 = new File("test2.png");
final WorldImageWriter wiWriter = new WorldImageWriter(out2);

// writing parameters for png
final Format writerFormat = wiWriter.getFormat();

// setting write parameters
final ParameterValueGroup params = writerFormat.getWriteParameters();
params.parameter(WorldImageFormat.FORMAT.getName().toString()).setValue("png");
final GeneralParameterValue[] gpv = {
    params.parameter(WorldImageFormat.FORMAT.getName().toString())
};
GridCoverageFactory factory = CoverageFactoryFinder.getGridCoverageFactory(null);
GridCoverage2D coverage = factory.create("name", image, grid.getEnvelope());
// writing
wiWriter.write(coverage , gpv);
wiWriter.dispose();
//write out the prj file too
File prj = new File("test2.prj");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(prj);
pw.print(coverage.getCoordinateReferenceSystem().toWKT());
pw.close();
```